# How to make Flutter Web scrollable?

Tags: flutter

I am trying to make a website with Flutter. I have a code like this:

```
class say2 extends StatefulWidget {
  say2({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  State<say2> createState() => _say2State();
}

class _say2State extends State<say2> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Text("Merhaba dünya"),
        Text("Merhaba dünya"),
        Text("Merhaba dünya"),
        Text("Merhaba dünya"),
        Text("Merhaba dünya"),
        Text("Merhaba dünya"),
        Text("Merhaba dünya"),
        Text("Merhaba dünya"),
        Text("Merhaba dünya"),
        Text("Merhaba dünya"),
        Text("Merhaba dünya"),
        Text("Merhaba dünya"),
        Text("Merhaba dünya"),
        Text("Merhaba dünya"),
        Text("Merhaba dünya"),
        Text("Merhaba dünya"),
        Text("Merhaba dünya"),
        Text("Merhaba dünya"),
        Text("Merhaba dünya"),
        Text("Merhaba dünya"),
        Text("Merhaba dünya"),
        Text("Merhaba dünya"),
        Text("Merhaba dünya"),
        Text("Merhaba dünya"),
        Text("Merhaba dünya"),
        Text("Merhaba dünya"),
        Text("Merhaba dünya"),
        Text("Merhaba dünya"),
        Text("Merhaba dünya"),
        Text("Merhaba dünya"),
        Text("Merhaba dünya"),
        Text("Merhaba dünya"),
        Text("Merhaba dünya"),
        Text("Merhaba dünya"),
        Text("Merhaba dünya"),
        Text("Merhaba dünya"),
        Text("Merhaba dünya"),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

But the screen goes like this:

[image]

I want these articles to be scrollable downwards. Why could this be? How can I do it? Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [`ListView`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView-class.html)

```dart
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView(
      children: [
        Text("Merhaba dünya"),
        Text("Merhaba dünya"),
        Text("Merhaba dünya"),
        Text("Merhaba dünya"),
        Text("Merhaba dünya"),
        Text("Merhaba dünya"),
        Text("Merhaba dünya"),
        Text("Merhaba dünya"),
        Text("Merhaba dünya"),
        Text("Merhaba dünya"),
        Text("Merhaba dünya"),
        Text("Merhaba dünya"),
        Text("Merhaba dünya"),
        Text("Merhaba dünya"),
        Text("Merhaba dünya"),
        Text("Merhaba dünya"),
        Text("Merhaba dünya"),
        Text("Merhaba dünya"),
        Text("Merhaba dünya"),
        Text("Merhaba dünya"),
        Text("Merhaba dünya"),
        Text("Merhaba dünya"),
        Text("Merhaba dünya"),
        Text("Merhaba dünya"),
        Text("Merhaba dünya"),
        Text("Merhaba dünya"),
        Text("Merhaba dünya"),
        Text("Merhaba dünya"),
        Text("Merhaba dünya"),
        Text("Merhaba dünya"),
        Text("Merhaba dünya"),
        Text("Merhaba dünya"),
        Text("Merhaba dünya"),
        Text("Merhaba dünya"),
        Text("Merhaba dünya"),
        Text("Merhaba dünya"),
        Text("Merhaba dünya"),
      ],
    );
  }
```

If possible, it is better to use the [`.builder`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView/ListView.builder.html) constructor to take advantage of the [lazy loading](https://medium.com/@archelangelo/flutter-load-contents-lazily-on-scroll-made-simple-c6817f94e5d0):

```dart
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: 50,
      builder: (context, index) {
        return Text("Merhaba dünya");
      },
    );
  }
```